# Rendering bug on ':before' when using 'content' in CSS

Tags: css, rendering

I'm using anchor tags with 'content' set on :before to be : "——";

```
a.line {
font-size: 21px;
font-family: Khula,sans-serif;
display: inline-block;}

a.line:before {
content: "——";
padding-right: 25px;
font-weight: 400;
font-family: serif;
font-size: 24px;
letter-spacing: -10px;
transition: all .3s;}
```

Sometimes they render like this:

[image]

When they should render like this:

[image]

It doesn't happen every time the page loads, and appears to just happen at random. Has anyone encountered this before and found a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have no idea if this fixes your problem but the correct way to declare a **pseudo-element** is with `::before`, single colon declaration is for **pseudo-classes**

Answer (score 0):

Use the Unicode value instead. An em dash is U+2014

```
content:"\002014";
```